# Objective C programmatically View ViewController But Black Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, storyboard

When debugging, viewDidLoad of LoginViewController is called, but the screen is black screen. I really don't know why..

```
@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) AppCoordinator *appCoordinator;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    
    //UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: vc];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}
```

LoginViewController.m

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"LoginViewController viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    
}


@end
```

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, why have this code at all? Just let the storyboard do its thing.

Comment: Screen conversion using the coordinator pattern is a basic step to implement with code.

Comment: You don’t assert on nil vc

Comment: That part seems to be a part that needs to be improved.. but it is not the cause of the above problem.. :(

Comment: The issue comes from some other part of your code, i believe. I.e. check view hierarchy of the "black screen" and inspect why `LoginViewController` ends up with that result (it could be that something is broken on the storyboard, or in the `LoginViewController` code)

Comment: Have you accidentally set the background color to black? I guess its view controller background color or the view controller's view is covered by its subView, which is black. Try to debug UI.

Comment: If this is a modern project it will use the scene lifecycle and your code for configuring the window should be in the scene delegate, not the app delegate.

Comment: @GeoffHackworth

That cause was correct. Thank you.